# customevalidator is not working as expected during validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

Hi  I am validating the textbox against checkbox checked state using custom validator..

if  checkbox checked false and textbox is empty it should throw an error like required CertID like that ... I put breakpoint in this method "cvCertId_OnServerValidate" it is not hitting at all when i click on submit button...

But I am not able to get the error when i click on the submit button..

this is my aspx code

```
<div class="SearchLine">
            <div class="Firstlbl">
                <asp:Label ID="Lbl1" runat="server" Text=" CertificateID *" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="firstTxtBox">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCertificateID" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            <div class="rfvValidation">
          <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvCertId" runat="Server"  OnServerValidate="cvCertId_OnServerValidate" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Validate" CssClass="validationerror"></asp:CustomValidator>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="SearchLine">
            <div class="chkboxLine">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSerialNumber" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkSerialNumber_CheckedChanged" />
            </div>
            <div class="Firstlbl">
                <asp:Label ID="Lbl2" runat="server" Text="Serial Number *" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="firstTxtBox">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCertificateSerialNumber" runat="server" Width="300px" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="rfvValidation">
               <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvSerialNumber" runat="Server"   OnServerValidate="cvSerialNumber_OnServerValidate" Display="dynamic" ValidationGroup="Validate" CssClass="validationerror"></asp:CustomValidator>
            </div>
        </div>

   <div class="SearchResetControls">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Re-Assign" 
                onclick="btnSubmit_Click" ValidationGroup="Validate"/>
        </div>
         <div runat="server" id="divMessage">
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

and this is my aspx.cs code

```
    protected void cvCertId_OnServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (chkSerialNumber.Checked == false)
        {
            string certID = txtCertificateID.Text;
            if (certID == string.Empty)
            {
                ((CustomValidator)sender).ErrorMessage = "Required Certificate Id";
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void cvSerialNumber_OnServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (chkSerialNumber.Checked == true && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCertificateSerialNumber.Text))
        {
            ((CustomValidator)sender).ErrorMessage = "Required Certificate Serial Number";
            args.IsValid = false;

        }
    }
```

Would any one please help on this

many thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove ControlToValidate property in your custom validation controls. and Add Text and ErrorMessage properties. For example,

```
<div class="firstTxtBox">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCertificateSerialNumber" runat="server" Width="300px" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="rfvValidation">
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvSerialNumber" runat="Server"   OnServerValidate="cvSerialNumber_OnServerValidate" Display="dynamic" ValidationGroup="Validate" CssClass="validationerror" Text="Error" ErrorMessage="This is error message"></asp:CustomValidator>
</div>
```

Comment: I have changed my answer. I personally have tested this solution on my computer and it is working. Text attribute is not a mandatory. But ErrorMessage is required to display the message especially when you use ValidationSummary control.